# Wireshark shows no packets list

Tags: wireshark

My *Wireshark* shows no packet list while capturing or when displaying a tcpdump-ed file:

[image]

Column headers are there but the list is empty, although details of single packets are shown.

Anybody who experienced the same problem?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, Wireshark Version 1.10.6 (v1.10.6 from master-1.10).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: true that @jww but I just had the same problem, and it was impossible to find the source of the problem myself. Without this post here I'd have had to stick to tshark.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid it was simply hidden by the *Packet Details* part. Dragging down the borderline, there the filthy head of the *Packets List* part comes out:

[image]

Summary of commands to install wireshark without requiring root permissions on *Ubuntu*:

```
> sudo apt-get install wireshark
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
> sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
> sudo reboot
```